# Приставка "при-" в значении неполноты качества

Tags: лингвистика

По идее, приставка "при-" означает действие приближения к чему-то или близость к чему-то: "пригород", "приставка". А вот интересно значение "при-" в таких словах, как "придурок", "пригорок". Тут нет ни расположения рядом с чем-то, ни движения. Как тогда?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для успешного решения задач, связвнных с выбором ПРЕ/ПРИ  желательно установить их центральное (обобщенное) значение. Таким центральным значением приставки ПРИ является обобщенное значение приближения к предмету, признаку или действию, которое   частным образом может выражаться  как расположение около предмета, направленность на предмет, присоединение или добавление к предмету и другие значения.

Гора – пригорок, дурак - при дурок - это значение уподобления предмету. Пригорок не расположен рядом с горой, это просто маленькая горка, небольшой холм. И дурак - это дурак не совершенный, а только отчасти.

Answer (score 5):

Кроме указанных значений, приставка ПРИ обозначает ещё неполноту действия. Здесь хоть и не действие, но признак не в полную силу выражен: пригорок - небольшая гора, придурок - не совсем дурак. А в словаре Ушакова у слова "пригорок" еще указано значение "холм у подножия горы", может, и значение близости было в слове.

Comment: Неполноту действия можно также рассмотреть как приближение к основному действию, а частными значениями будут неполнота действия и сопровождение действия: открыть - приоткрыть, петь - припевать.